# Call a flow to create an OutLook event using the users' timezone.. is this possible?

Tags: office-365, user-profile, power-automate, powerapp, timezone

I have this form inside our canvas app to call a flow which create an event:-

[image: johnjohnPter_0-1701812998718.png]

and this is the code inside the Save button:-

```
    WFHSendInviteToCalender.Run(
        "{  
    ""WFHId"": " & Last(NewWFHEntry).ID & ",
    ""Subject"": ""WFO - " & User().FullName & """,
    ""StartTime"": """ & ThisRecord.SelectedStartTime & """,
    ""EndTime"": """ &  ThisRecord.SelectedEndTime & """,
    ""AllDayEvent"": " & !tgAllDayEvent_1.Value & ",
    ""RequiredEmail"": """ & If(
            IsBlank(varCountryAccountEmail),
            varDefaultCountryAccountEmail,
            varCountryAccountEmail
        ) & """,
    ""Body"": """ &  "  
 Hi,
I am Working from office from " & Text(DateTimeValue(ThisRecord.SelectedStartTime),"hh:mm AM/PM") & " " & (ThisRecord.SelectedDate) & " - " & Text(DateTimeValue(ThisRecord.SelectedEndTime),"hh:mm AM/PM") & " " & (ThisRecord.SelectedDate) & " with full access to email.
<br />
Thank you,
" & User().FullName & "
  " & """
}"
    );
```

and here is the create event action inside the flow:-

[image: johnjohnPter_1-1701813045751.png]

now  most of our users are based on the US & Canada time zone, so the above work for them. but some of them are based in the UK & Berlin, where when they select to create a half day (first half, which is 9AM to 5 PM), the value inside their calendars will be showing as 7PM to 3 AM ... so is there a way to create the Event inside the flow using the Timezone of the user who is running the power apps and calling the flow? instead of hardcoding it to US & Canada?

Thanks

Comment: You can get `user mailbox timezone` with Graph API https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get-mailboxsettings?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http So are you confortable to make a Power Automate flow with the premium HTTP connector, or better, create a custom connector?

Comment: @jleture thanks for the advice , but how i can convert the Graph API time zone to the Power Automate time zone for the Events action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify time zone directly in the datetime field of the `Create event (V4)` action, and let `UTC` as the timezone.

For example, for UTC-5:

```
2023-12-07T09:00:00-0500
2023-12-07T13:00:00-0500
```

Or, for UTC+1:

```
2023-12-07T09:00:00+0100
2023-12-07T13:00:00+0100
```

So you can adapt the datetime string with the user timezone. You can get user regional setting with Graph API https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get-mailboxsettings?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http or you can add a combobox in your Power Apps to select a timezone.

[image: timezone]

The datetime will be converted to be displayed with user regional settings. For a user with an UTC+1 calendar, the event `2023-12-07T09:00:00+0100` will start at 9am and the event `2023-12-07T09:00:00-0500` will start 6 hours later (at 3pm). For a user with an UTC-5 calendar, the event `2023-12-07T09:00:00-0500` will start at 9am and the event `2023-12-07T09:00:00+0100` was started 6 hours earlier (at 3am)

##### Calendar with UTC+1

[image: calendar utc+1]

##### Calendar with UTC-5

[image: calendar utc-5]

Comment: thanks for the advice , will try and update you how it works